# Intergrating Opencv into hexagon DSP

Tags: android, opencv, hexagon-dsp

I want to include Opencv to Hexagon DSP. What i want to ask is how to add opencv to android.min file. When we want to add opencv to android project we simple give the path of opencv.mk in our make file(Android.mk) but hexagon dsp uses some make.d library which  has android.min so now how do i include opencv into that.